# REST API 12MB Limit

Tags: json, rest, heap

I'm receiving a PDF in Base64 from an external web service, the PDF is received in JSON along with some other details. Is there anything I can do to avoid the Heap size being blown when converting the JSON to a string? I've already tried using a @future method to increase the Heap to 12MB but the requirements state that a larger PDF may be sent. Without using an external service to deserialize I'm not sure if this is possible. Also, a second PDF may be included within the same payload.

JSON Example:

```
{
    ID:"xxxx",
    Info: {
      contract: "xxxx",
      Location: "xxxx",
      Code: "xxxx",
      form: "xxxx",
      Action:"xxxx", 
      DateTime: "xxxx",
      Description:"xxxx", 
      PDF1:  "xxxx",
      PDF2: "xxxx"
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The governor limits are (mostly) absolute. You especially cannot violate the 6MB/12MB limits for callouts. You would need to use an external service (e.g. Heroku, Amazon AWS).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, that pointed me in the right direction. Ended up using the attachments API and sequencing the order that the PDFs are received in. For anyone looking for this in future the below will hopefully help:

https://XXXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Document/